# tools open source to help in search

Tags: java, php

Please Can you give me the name of tools open source witch can help somebody to search some information like google .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give more detailed information about what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene is a text indexing and searching library. Maybe you would like to start from that. It is available atleast for java and .net

Comment: There's also Zend Search Lucene, for PHP. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to take a loot at [Sphinx Search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/)

It is great for full text search, at ast we have used it for archives of a daily newspaper and it was pretty successful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use [**Sphider**](http://www.sphider.eu/). It's free, has "did you mean?" function too. You can set number of subpages and links it will menshion in the URL. Very useful thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Lucene](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LuceneSearch), [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/) (based on Lucene), [mnogo search](http://www.mnogosearch.org/), [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/), [Xapian](http://xapian.org/), [ht::dig](http://www.htdig.org/), ::egother, zettair, terrier.....

Google offer [Sitesearch](http://www.google.co.uk/sitesearch) a search service which is relatively cheap - but neither software nor open source